# What was the first trailer to use "in a world"?

Tags: first-appearance, trailers

In a world where it's a common joke that trailers contain the phrase "in a world"...and there are even [lists](http://screencrush.com/in-a-world-trailers/) of trailers that used the phrase seriously, as an artifact of a world where a trailer containing "in a world" wasn't a joke...One man...is curious what trailer originated this phrase. But to find out...he's going to have to ask a question...on Movies and TV SE.

**What was the earliest trailer to use the phrase "in a world"?** The earliest movie on that list is *The Road Warrior*, from 1981. Was it the first, or was there an earlier one?

Comment: So, the trailer actually stated that one man is going to have to ask a question on Movies and TV SE?

Comment: @steelerfan No, that wording was supposed to be humorous. "One (man/woman/etc.)" is another thing they say in trailers. The question is written like the kind of stereotypical trailer that it's asking about. I'm not suggesting or claiming that there is a real trailer which mentions Stack Exchange.

Comment: You could try to look into Don Lafontaine's filmography - he was the most iconic deep voice to do trailers back in the days...

Answer (score 4):

As said in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_LaFontaine):

> Donald Leroy LaFontaine (August 26, 1940 – September 1, 2008) was an
>   American voice actor who recorded more than 5,000 film trailers and
>   hundreds of thousands of television advertisements, network
>   promotions, and video game trailers.
>
> **He became identified with the phrase "In a world..."**, used in so many
>   movie trailers that it became a cliché. Widely known in the film
>   industry, his nicknames included "Thunder Throat" and "The
>   Voice of God".
>
> LaFontaine claimed that **company National Recording Studios** he worked for **first came up with** many of the famous movie trailer catch phrases, including his own future signature phrase, **"in a world..."**.

Answer (score 0):

Donald Leroy "Don" LaFontaine claimed he was the first to come up with the idea however there is no proof of it but it seems to have been around for some time.

Comment: Can you provide some sources for your answer please?